# Angular $resource not working correctly

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build my first Angular `$resource` to give my application access to CRUD operations, but for some reason the actions being configured for the resource are not defined when I try to execute a query.

Here is my controller logic:

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $resource) {

                var Alert = $resource('/WebApi/Alert/:type/:id',
                {
                    systemUpdate: { method: 'GET' },
                    autoArchive: { method: 'POST', url: '/WebApi/Alert/Template/:type' }
                });

                $scope.systemUpdate = function (alert) {
                    var data = Alert.systemUpdate({ type: alert.Status, id: alert.AlertId }); // THIS LINE FAILS
                    console.log(data);
                }
```

I get an error saying that Alert.systemUpdate is not defined. Am I doing something wrong here when configuring my `$resource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of your Alert to

```
var Alert = $resource('/WebApi/Alert/:type/:id',
{},
{
   systemUpdate: { method: 'GET' },
   autoArchive: { method: 'POST', url: '/WebApi/Alert/Template/:type' }
});
```

As mentionned in the documentation of [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource), the order of the parameters is the following:

1) Url

2) The default value of the parameters of the url, since you don't have any default value, you must provide an empty object

3) The actions (systemUpdate & autoArchive here)

Comment: Oh ok so you have to specific that parameter no matter what, I see. Ok thanks!

Comment: @Matt Hintzke You have to specify this parameter only if you define specific actions (i.e. other than the default get, save, query, remove and delete).